# keras - embedding layer, can I alter values of a trained embedding layer in the pipeline of a model?

Tags: keras, embedding

I am following examples on this page: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/

which trains a word embedding on the data using an Embedding layer, like below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(100, 8, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
```

the model starts with learning a word embedding from data, for each word, creates a 8-dimension vector.

What I would like to do, is that after this embedding is learned, I want to alter the matrix (or vectors of each word), by adding two more dimensions appended to the end of each vector. I will have another process that computes the values for this two dimensions.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - it's possible. Try to do this using following procedure:

1. Extract weight matrix:

   ```
   weight_matrix = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0] # Matrix shape (100, 8).
   ```
2. Append your vectors:

   ```
   new_weight_matrix = your_append(weight_matrix)
   # Be sure that new_weight_matrix has shape of (100, 10)
   ```
3. Build an adjusted copy of your model:

   ```
   new_model = Sequential()
   new_model.add(Embedding(100, 10, input_length=max_length)) # Notice a change
   new_model.add(Flatten())
   new_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   ```
4. (Optional) freeze layers: In case you want to freeze embedding set:

   ```
   new_model = Sequential()
   new_model.add(Embedding(100, 10, input_length=max_length
       trainable=False)) # Notice a change
   new_model.add(Flatten())
   new_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   ```
5. Compile a new model:

   ```
   new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
   ```

Comment: Thank you. And does this all have to come after the previous model has called 'compiled' and fitted on the data?

Comment: You need to refit your model - as it's architecture changed.

Comment: Thanks I understand refitting... I mean the previous model, I suppose it must be fitted to obtain the weights, right? Then I use your code to refit the model after modifying the matrix

Comment: Right. Your approach seems plausible. You may test it against freezing and not freezing layer.

Comment: Hi - was my answer helpful - if yes, I'd appreciate acceptance and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

After `compile` and `fit`, you need to replace the weights with the new ones:
`new_model.layers[0].set_weights(new_weight_matrix)`